# Can emacs replace multitail?

Tags: logging

I often fire up a multitail

```
multitail -f log/development.log
```

Then I hit my development website with chrome.
And then I add a regexp filter to show only lines matching the word "Processing "

Can this be done without in emacs? why I'm trying to avoid multitail

```
its curses based, and won't work well with M-x shell
it has strict requirements about minimum window size
```